# PHP variable in JavaScript doesn't print

Tags: javascript, php

I've been reading all the questions about how to print a PHP variable in JavaScript but all the answers I read until now don't work for me and I'm going crazy.
This is my code:

```
<?php
$MyPHPStringVar = '321321';
$MyPHPNumVar = 32;
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>o maior</title>
    </head>
    <body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var MyJSStringVar = "<?php Print($MyPHPStringVar); ?>";
    var MyJSNumVar = <?php Print($MyPHPNumVar); ?>;
    alert(MyJSStringVar);
    alert(MyJSNumVar);
</script>


    </body>
</html>
```

When I run this the alert() shows "" for my phpstring variable and doesn't show nothing for my php number variable.
Why is this?? I'm going nuts because it seems to work for everybody but not me!!
Thanks for your time

Comment: Try using `echo` rather than `Print`

Comment: Is your server set up to parse PHP in our given file type?

Comment: Try using echo($variable); instead.

Comment: `print`, not `Print`

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/f9z-n4a).

Comment: @don: php functions are NOT case sensitive. Only variables are.

Comment: @Don: [Doesn't matter](http://3v4l.org/cpggJ) -- function are case-insensitive.

Comment: your code works fine on my machine, however embedding php variable in js code is a bad practice to me, especially in scenarios that js files and php files are separated. Try using ajax instead of embedding php variable directly.

Comment: @MarcB oh! didn't know that.Thanks for the info :). But looks better lowercase

Comment: @Redgie, didn't work also. I tried that before.

Comment: I don't know ajax @aarryy. What I'm trying to do is to create a function to use in flot charts to read a file and update a realtime plot constantly. But first I need to be able to read that file and make JavaScript read the variable. That was what I was doing with PHP.

Comment: @Fricker I don't know. Well I'm just coding in Microsoft WebMatrix and previewing it on Firefox. I thought that was enough to make things work!

Comment: Make sure the apache server is running properly. Echo the variables in the php first and see if they show up in the page

Comment: @PedroTairum as @Amal Muralis said, this works.Is a `.php` file ?

Comment: Why would it make any difference here whether you use print or echo?

Comment: @PedroTairum try using a testing server such as uniserver www.uniformserver.com, its the simplest testing server to set up and use!

Comment: IT WORKS FINE CHECK IF YOU ARE RUNNING THIS UNDER `PHP PLATFORM`

Comment: @K3rnel31 no capital letters please

Comment: Can you provide us with the generated source code in your browser? What's inside your script tags when you check that?

Comment: btw, just because PHP is case insensitive doesnt make it a good practice! ;)

Comment: If that is your actual and complete PHP file, there has to be something wrong with wour php engine or server. Code looks correct!

Comment: I know. I was just recommended to instal XAMPP. I'm going to do it and then try again. Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: @MarcB: actually `print` is not a real function, but a language construct^^

Answer (score 0):

use this instead :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php echo " var MyJSStringVar = "\".$MyPHPStringVar.""\";
    var MyJSNumVar = <?php echo $MyPHPNumVar; ?>;
    alert(MyJSStringVar);
    alert(MyJSNumVar);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use echo instead of Print. Something like -

```
var MyJSNumVar = <?php echo $MyPHPNumVar; ?>;
```

Also if your php.ini has short tags turned on you can use -

```
var MyJSNumVar = <?=$MyPHPNumVar?>;
```

Comment: You might want to do "echo (int)$MyPHPNumVar;" otherwise zero variables might come out as empty strings.

Comment: Can you try printing the variables at the top inside the PHP section itself - just to makes sure the variables are being assigned in the first place? Something like -
<?php
    $MyPHPStringVar = '321321';
    $MyPHPNumVar = 32;
    echo $MyPHPStringVar;
    echo $MyPHPNumVar;
?>

Answer (score 0):

@ToBe, here is the code:

```
<?php
$MyPHPStringVar = '321321';
$MyPHPNumVar = 32;



?><!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>o maior</title>
    </head>
    <body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var MyJSStringVar = "<?php print($MyPHPStringVar); ?>";
    var MyJSNumVar = <?php print($MyPHPNumVar); ?>;
    alert(MyJSStringVar);
    alert(MyJSNumVar);
</script>


    </body>
</html>
```

It's the same!

Answer (score 0):

It was an error on the PHP engine.
I reinstalled it with Microsoft Web Plataform Installer along with the new ISS8.0 and it's working great!